# Error java IO total size of folder

Tags: java, file, io

my program counts and prints out the number of files of folder and the total size in bytes of all files but i have error ("Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException")

```
import java.io.*;
public class Ex5 {
    public static void a(String s) throws IOException{

        long size=0;
        File f=new File(s);
        File [] a=f.listFiles();
        System.out.println("the number of files in this folder :"+a.length);
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(a[i].isFile()){
            size=size+a[i].length();

        }else
            a(a[i].getName());

        }
    System.out.println("the folder size is :"+size);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      a("C:\\Users\\hackour\\Documents\\javablue\\applet");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're assuming `File[] a = f.listFiles()` will always result in a non-null value. this isn't true for empty directories and files. try adding some guard code for this condition, like:

```
    ...
    File[] a = f.listFiles();
    if(a != null) {
        System.out.println("the number of files in this folder :" + a.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i].isFile()) {
                size = size + a[i].length();

            } else
                a(a[i].getName());

        }
    }
    System.out.println("the folder size is :" + size);
    ...
```

Comment: first the program is fine print the the total size of folder applet but when i creat new folder in folder applet the program make this error
i put if(a!=null)
but the program doesn't print the  total size of folder with the size of subfolder
thx for help
NOTE:("first the applet folder have only files")

Comment: the problem was in a(a[i].getName());
it should be size+=a(a[i].getname());